# How can I change my subselect I can get multiple rows with WHERE IN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT TOP 1 obj FROM rel_raci responsible_raci_r WHERE responsible_raci_r.PERSON_ID = organization.id AND responsible_raci_r.RACI ='R') AS responsible_inverted,
  (SELECT TOP 1 obj FROM rel_raci responsible_raci_r WHERE responsible_raci_r.PERSON_ID = organization.id AND responsible_raci_r.RACI ='A') AS accountable_inverted,
  (SELECT TOP 1 obj FROM rel_raci responsible_raci_r WHERE responsible_raci_r.PERSON_ID = organization.id AND responsible_raci_r.RACI ='C') AS consulted_inverted,
  (SELECT TOP 1 obj FROM rel_raci responsible_raci_r WHERE responsible_raci_r.PERSON_ID = organization.id AND responsible_raci_r.RACI ='I') AS informed_inverted 
FROM obj_resource organization
WHERE CONTAINS('2cef8e3d:15992b7f51e:33f', organization.id, -1) AND getOrgtype(organization.id) != 1
```

Comment: maybe moving the subselect in from clause and using a join, aliases may be shorter than actual tables

Comment: LEFT JOIN, just in case.

Comment: i tried this, but somehow its not working: 

SELECT id
FROM obj_resource organization
WHERE obj IN (SELECT  obj FROM rel_raci  responsible_raci_r WHERE responsible_raci_r.PERSON_ID = organization.id AND responsible_raci_r.RACI ='R'  ) AS responsible_inverted

 -- Gibt nur die markierten Massnahmen aus
WHERE CONTAINS('2cef8e3d:15992b7f51e:33f', organization.id ,-1 ) AND getOrgtype(organization.id) != 1

Comment: MySQL does not support `TOP` or `CONTAINS()`, so your question doesn't make sense.  Sample data, desired results, and appropriate tags are all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for what you are asking would be:

```
SELECT {columns_list}
  FROM {table_name}
 WHERE {column_name} IN (SELECT {column_name}
                           FROM {table_name}
                          WHERE {condition(s)}
                        ) A ;
```

Comment: Ok I will try it again

Comment: like this? 

SELECT id
FROM obj_resource organization
WHERE obj IN (SELECT  obj FROM rel_raci  responsible_raci_r WHERE responsible_raci_r.PERSON_ID = organization.id AND responsible_raci_r.RACI ='R'  ) AS responsible_inverted

WHERE CONTAINS('2cef8e3d:15992b7f51e:33f', organization.id ,-1 ) AND getOrgtype(organization.id) != 1

Comment: Well, you have some syntax errors (like wrong `)` at some places and missing `)` at others, but the general idea is correct. Note also that in SQL you don't write `!=` for not-equal but `<>`. Last, if my answer was helpful, it us custom to vote for it. Thanks.